# Oracle - How to save table as csv file from terminal with command

Tags: linux, oracle, csv, terminal

I have this process to save a table to CSV file but is not perfect:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba

set heading off

SET TERMOUT OFF
spool MY_TABLE.csv

select column_id||','||column_name||','||data_type||','||nullable||','||data_length from user1.MY_TABLE;

spool off;

exit
```

Issue with that is that can not turn off printing to terminal (I have SET TERMOUT OFF but that does not suppress the output for some reason).
I would like to run a sqlplus with a query from a terminal (instead of opening sqlplus and running from there).. 
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example 1 for linux `create_csv.sh` displays the table data on the monitor screen.

```
    #!/bin/sh

    sqlplus -s /  as sysdba <<EOF
    set heading off
    set termout OFF
    SET FEEDBACK OFF
    SET TAB OFF
    set pause off
    set verify off
    SET UNDERLINE OFF
    set trimspool on
    set timing off
    set echo off
    set linesize 1000
    set pagesize 0
    SET COLSEP ','
    spool test2.csv
    select code,name,code_rail from alexs.all_station;
    spool off
    exit;
    EOF
```

Example 2 for linux `createv2_csv.sh`  does not display anything.

```
#!/bin/sh

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /  as sysdba @csv2.sql
```

csv2.sql  removed spaces and tabs between fields in the output file test2.csv

```
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set wrap off
spool test2.csv
select code||','||name||','||code_rail from alexs.all_station;
spool off
exit;
```

Example for Windows `test_csv.bat`

```
sqlplus -s  user/password@net_alias  < csv.sql
```

csv.sql

```
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set timing off
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
SET COLSEP ','
spool test.csv
select code,name,code_rail from alexs.all_station;
spool off
exit;
```

Example for Windows powershell script `create_csv.ps1`

```
# login DBA user
$username_dba = "system"
# PASSWORD DBA user !!!!
$password_dba = "manager"

# Connect without alias 
$tnsalias_db = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test.com)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = test)))"

$sqlQuery = 
@"
set heading off
set termout OFF
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET TAB OFF
set pause off
set verify off
SET UNDERLINE OFF
set trimspool on
set timing off
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
SET COLSEP ','
spool test.csv
select code,name,code_rail from alexs.all_station;
spool off
exit
"@

$sqlOutput = $sqlQuery | sqlplus -silent $username_dba/$password_dba@$tnsalias_db
```

Example output test.csv

```
    966203,ГУРСКОЕ                  ,        96
    966307,УКТУР                    ,        96
    966400,КЕНАЙ                    ,        96
    966504,ВЫСОКОГОРНАЯ             ,        96
    966608,КЕНАДА                   ,        96
    966805,ТУЛУЧИ                   ,        96
    966909,АКУР                     ,        96
    967009,ТУМНИН                   ,        96
    967102,ХУТУ                     ,        96
    967206,УСТЬ-ОРОЧИ               ,        96
    967305,МОНГОХТО                 ,        96
    967403,ЛАНДЫШИ                  ,        96
    967526,ТОКИ                     ,        96
    967600,ВАНИНО                   ,        96
    967704,ВАНИНО-ПЕРЕВАЛКА         ,        96
    967808,ВАНИНО-ЭКСПОРТ           ,        96
    968001,ВИНЕВИТИНО               ,        96
```

Example output test2.csv

```
971907,ВЯЗЕМСКАЯ,96
972007,АВАН,96
972100,РОЗЕНГАРТОВКА,96
972204,БИКИН,96
972308,ЗВЕНЬЕВОЙ,96
972401,БУРЛИТ-ВОЛОЧАЕВСКИЙ,96
972505,ЛУЧЕГОРСК,96
972609,ЛАСТОЧКА,96
972702,ГУБЕРОВО,96
972721,ЭБЕРГАРД,96
972806,ДАЛЬНЕРЕЧЕНСК I,96
973207,ДАЛЬНЕРЕЧЕНСК II,96
973300,ЛАЗО,96
973404,ГРУШЕВОЕ,96
973508,ПРОХАСКО,96
973601,ФИЛАРЕТОВКА,96
973705,РУЖИНО,96
973809,ЛЕСОЗАВОДСК I,96
973813,1634 КМ,96
973902,ШМАКОВКА,96
974002,СУНГАЧ,96
974106,СВИЯГИНО,96
974229,ДРОЗДОВ,96
```

Comment: Thanks.. This first example is good start (can run outside of sqlplus) but output seems like adding TABs or SPACES where only comma is needed between 2 columns.. Also - output is displayed in terminal window so if table has 1M records - it will print 1M lines on the screen before it finishes (slow)..

Comment: Your windows redirection operator should be `>` and not `<`

Comment: @Joe I added Example 2 without displaying the terminal and without extra tabs and spaces between the columns.

Comment: @PatrickBacon This redirection operator `<` reads the sql command  input from the file `csv.sql`.  This is equivalent to `sqlplus -s  user/pass@tns_alias @csv.sql`